# Php artisan command Run out memory with 32Gb of RAM

Tags: php, laravel-4.2

I have in DigitalOcean a droplet of 32Gb ram with 12 CPU (resize for occasion)

I run php artisan command (laravel 4.2) which never ran. What could be happening?
[image: Ram monitoring]

And the error message after more than 10 minutes: 
[image]

Comment: Your PHP ran out of memory, most likely. You'll have to adjust your [PHP memory limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

Comment: @aynber Thanks for comenting, I have my memory limit in php.ini with -1, still don't knowing the source of problem here. And I don't having a complex migration: https://pastebin.com/xywEfqqz

Comment: I think it's not even reading the script.

Comment: It actually did really run out of all 32G of memory (34233909248/1024/1024/1024 = 31.88). I'd suggest you look at your migration to see what might be causing that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see anything out of the ordinary with your migration, unless it's trying to throw an error.

Comment: your MySQL client is opening thousands of connections for some reason and using 156Mb each thats eating your memory so it seems like the code s opening new connections to the database in an infinite loop

Comment: also note that mysql server will try to use all available memory if it's not configured not to as the more stuff in memory the quicker to access try moving your mysql server to another droplet

Comment: Hello, @MartinBarker @aynber thanks for commenting and the ideas. Yesterday I solved the problem, for some reason MySQL was consuming the RAM in an infinite loop. I drop the database, created a new one. But the solution was updating composer. as I was on a server, fetch with git the new composer.lock and run `sudo composer install` is not recommendable use the sudo with composer, but had to. Then, run the `php artisan`and everything works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question, with the help of @aynber and @MartinBarker

I solved the problem droping the current database, updating composer (`composer update` in my local and pushing composer.lock which contain the updates to the server, in the server run `composer install` with sudo (is not recommendable use sudo with composer.) and runing `sudo php artisan`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

then edit the php.ini file and increase your memory limit

[image]